# How do I stop color changes when quitting vi from a terminal emulator?

Tags: 12.04, server, vim, command-line

I have a problem with colors when using `vi` under Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm connecting to my Ubuntu server from a PC, using PowerTerm terminal
emulation software.  I have PowerTerm set up to display black text on
a grey background.

When I connect to the Ubuntu box, the screen is fine.  When I open a file with `vi`, the screen is fine.  The text is black on a gray background, which is normal for my PowerTerm setup.  However, if the file is less than a full screen long, the remainder of the screen is a black background.  When I quit `vi`, the entire background turns black, and the text becomes white.  I have to do a Terminal Reset to restore my
normal text and background colors.

What I want is for there to be no change at all when I use `vi`.  The text should be black and the background grey.  I have another server loaded with RedHat 9, and that acts normally; colors don’t change when using `vi`.

Here is my `.vimrc` file:

```
set compatible
syntax off
let g:loaded_matchparen=1
set nocp
set noincsearch
set nohlsearch
set noshowmatch
set bg=dark
```

I've tried `set bg=dark` and `set bg=light`.  It makes no difference.  Is there some other set command that would clear this up for me, or some TERM setting (my TERM is set to linux)?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep the TERM setting same in both the computers. So just change it to whatever is in the server.

Note that you should keep the `set t_Co=256` setting in .vimrc for it to work properly, esp when connected remotely.